# How do I handle "TypeError: add_all_ta_features() got multiple values for keyword argument 'fillna'"?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm following this documentation: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/technical-analysis-library-in-python/latest/technical-analysis-library-in-python.pdf

Specifically page 9 of the PDF. Copying this code I get a type error. I'm not sure if that means I should edit my data file (which is just standard stock data) or edit the fillna portion of the code.

```
from ta import *

df = pd.read_csv('VRAY.csv', sep=',')
df = utils.dropna(df)

df = add_all_ta_features(df,"Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Adj_Close","Volume", fillna=True)
```

This is the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/toni/PycharmProjects/PyPractice/stockTA/techanal.py", line 7, in 
    df = add_all_ta_features(df,"Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Adj_Close","Volume", fillna=True)
TypeError: add_all_ta_features() got multiple values for keyword argument 'fillna'

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the `ta` module gives this example for calling `add_all_ta_features()`:

```
add_all_ta_features(df, "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume_BTC", fillna=True)
```

That call has five columns:

```
Open
High
Low
Close
Volume_BTC
```

But your call has seven columns:

```
Date
Open
High
Low
Close
Adj_Close
Volume
```

You're trying to use too many columns.

Answer (score 0):

From the [project repository](https://github.com/bukosabino/ta/blob/1cc8a4abb50d5400ac295e20d1e923e332fe7488/ta/wrapper.py), the signature of the `add_all_ta_features()` method is

```py
def add_all_ta_features(df, open, high, low, close, volume, fillna=False, colprefix=""):
```

By providing so many arguments in  your call, you are assigning a value to `fillna` positionally as "Adj_Close". You cannot subsequently provide another value as a keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

You added one more parameter to it...
As you wrote extra parameters (9 parameters), one parameter took place of "fillna"'s parameter.
So when you used fillna as keyword argument ("fillna=") it was written twice to the same parameter.

It should be written this way (7 parameters):

```
add_all_ta_features(df, "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume_BTC", fillna=True)
```

You can find more examples on ta's GitHub:
https://github.com/bukosabino/ta